How to induct on mapped sets or...?
Working on verifying a version of the counting inversions algorithm. I feel like pairMapSize has everything it needs but it times out instead. I could try to do induction on slices of the array but I would need to define a function to produce another set, like the set of all inversions starting at (xs[0], YY) but then it would be just another case of comparing sets sizes.
    predicate IsInverted(xs: seq<int>, i: int, j: int) {
        0 <= i < j < |xs| && xs[i] > xs[j]
    }

    function inversionSet(xs: seq<int>): set<(int,int)> {
        set i,j | 0 <= i < j < |xs| && IsInverted(xs, i, j) :: (i,j)
    }

    function pairSetMap(ss: set<(int, int)>, i: int): set<(int, int)> 
    {
        set pair | pair in ss :: (pair.0 + i, pair.1 + i)
    }

    lemma {:verify } {:timelimit 30} {:vcs_split_on_every_assert} pairMapSize(xs: seq<int>, i: int)
        requires 0 <= i
        ensures |pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)| == |inversionSet(xs)|
    {
        if inversionSet(xs) == {} {
            assert |inversionSet(xs)| == 0;
            assert pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i) == {};
            assert |pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)| == 0;
        }else{
            // forall x | x in inversionSet(xs)
            //     ensures (x.0+i, x.1+i) in pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)
            // {

            // }

            // forall x | x in pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)
            //     ensures (x.0-i, x.1-i) in inversionSet(xs)
            // {

            // }
            var ixs := inversionSet(xs);
            var pxs := pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i);
            var x :| x in inversionSet(xs);
            assert (x.0+i, x.1+i) in pxs;
            assert |ixs| == 1 + |ixs-{x}|;
            assert |pxs| == 1 + |pxs-{(x.0+i, x.1+i)}|;
            var removed: set<(int, int)> := {};
            var premoved: set<(int, int)> := {};
            var mixs := 0;
            var mpxs := 0;
            while ixs != {} 
                invariant ixs == inversionSet(xs)-removed
                invariant ixs <= inversionSet(xs)
                invariant ixs !! removed
                invariant pxs == pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)-premoved
                invariant pxs <= pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)-premoved
                invariant pxs !! premoved
                invariant forall x :: x in removed ==> (x.0+i, x.1+i) in premoved
                invariant forall x :: x in premoved ==> (x.0-i, x.1-i) in removed
                invariant mixs == |removed|
                invariant mpxs == |premoved|
                invariant mixs == mpxs
            {
                var x :| x in ixs;
                assert x !in removed;
                var mx := (x.0+i, x.1+i);
                assert mx !in premoved by {
                    if mx in premoved {
                        assert x in removed;
                        assert false;
                    }
                }
                assert mx in pxs;
                ixs := ixs - {x};
                pxs := pxs - {mx};
                mixs := mixs + 1;
                mpxs := mpxs + 1;
                removed := removed + {x};
                premoved := premoved + {mx};
            }
            assert ixs == {};
            assert pxs == {};
            assert removed == inversionSet(xs);
            assert premoved == pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i);
            calc {
                |inversionSet(xs)|;
                |removed|;
                mixs;
                mpxs;
                |premoved|;
                |pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)|;
            }

        }


This answer doesn't go into why above code is not able to verify but an alternate solution which I am able to verify. I discovered it in process
of writing recursive definition of pairSetMap. If I removed first post condition and only keep size post condition then some thinking will reveal that post condition doesn't necessary holds if (s.0 + i, s.1 + i) is already
in pairSetMap(ss - {i}). This nudged me to write first post condition. Now all
it needs was some asserts in else part.
predicate IsInverted(xs: seq<int>, i: int, j: int) {
    0 <= i < j < |xs| && xs[i] > xs[j]
}

function inversionSet(xs: seq<int>): set<(int,int)> {
    set i,j | 0 <= i < j < |xs| && IsInverted(xs, i, j) :: (i,j)
}

method pairSetMap(ss: set<(int, int)>, i: int) returns (r: set<(int, int)>) 
  ensures forall p :: p in ss <==> (p.0 + i, p.1 + i) in r
  ensures |r| == |ss|
{
    if |ss| < 1 {
      r := set pair | pair in ss :: (pair.0 + i, pair.1 + i);
    }
    else { 
        var s :| s in ss;
        var t := pairSetMap(ss - {s}, i);
        assert |t| == |ss - {s}|;
        assert |ss| == |ss - {s}| + 1;
        assert (s.0 + i, s.1 + i) !in t by {
           if (s.0 + i, s.1 + i) in t {
                assert (s.0, s.1) in ss - {s};
                assert (s.0, s.1) !in ss - {s};
           }
        }
        r := t + { (s.0 + i, s.1 + i) };
        assert |r| == |t| + 1;
    }
}


Thank you for your help as always!. The tricky thing is I need the function definition as lemma to finish verifying another part of the algorithm.

Another thing which I missed it in answer is if I convert method to function, I am not able to verify it (which solves your purpose if you use this function as specification), probably something is missing (feature parity) between how functions and methods verification conditions are emitted.

Your recursive solution helped me get on the right path.

So I think my problem came down to choosing the element in the pair consistently. I was able to finish the verification with the following.
 lemma pairMapSize(xs: seq<int>, i: int)
        ensures |pairSetMap(inversionSet(xs), i)| == |inversionSet(xs)|
    {
        pairSetMapLemma(inversionSet(xs), i);
    }

    function pmap(ps: (int, int), i: int): (int, int)
    {
        (ps.0 + i, ps.1 + i)
    }

    ghost function pairSetMap2(ss: set<(int, int)>, i: int): set<(int, int)> 
        ensures forall pair :: pair in ss ==> pmap(pair, i) in pairSetMap2(ss, i)
    {
        if ss == {} then
            assert |ss| == 0;
            {}
        else
            var pair :| pair in ss;
            {pmap(pair, i)} + pairSetMap2(ss-{pair}, i)
    }

    lemma pairSetMap2Inverse(ss: set<(int, int)>, i: int, pair: (int, int))
        requires pair in pairSetMap2(ss, i)
        ensures pmap(pair, -i) in ss
    {
    }
    //{:vcs_split_on_every_assert}
    lemma pairSetMap2Lemma(ss: set<(int, int)>, i: int)
        ensures |pairSetMap2(ss, i)| == |ss|
    {
        if ss == {} {
            assert |ss| == 0;
            assert |pairSetMap2(ss, i)| == 0;
        }else{
            var result := pairSetMap2(ss, i);
            var pair :| pair in ss && {pmap(pair, i)} + pairSetMap2(ss-{pair}, i) == result;
            var mpair := pmap(pair, i);
            assert mpair in result;
            pairSetMap2Lemma(ss-{pair}, i);
            assert pair !in ss-{pair};

            assert mpair !in pairSetMap2(ss-{pair}, i) by {
                if mpair in pairSetMap2(ss-{pair}, i) {
                    assert mpair in pairSetMap2(ss-{pair}, i);
                    pairSetMap2Inverse(ss-{pair}, i, mpair);
                    assert pmap(mpair, -i) in ss-{pair};
                    assert pmap(mpair, -i) == pair;
                    assert false;
                }
            }
            assert result == {mpair} + pairSetMap2(ss-{pair}, i);
            assert |result| == 1 + |pairSetMap2(ss-{pair}, i)|;
        }

    }

    lemma pairsEqual(ss: set<(int, int)>, i: int)
        ensures pairSetMap(ss, i) == pairSetMap2(ss, i)
    {
    }

    lemma pairSetMapLemma(ss: set<(int, int)>, i: int)
        ensures |pairSetMap(ss, i)| == |ss|
    {
        pairSetMap2Lemma(ss, i);
        pairsEqual(ss, i);
        assert |pairSetMap(ss, i)| == |pairSetMap2(ss, i)|;
        assert |pairSetMap(ss, i)| == |ss|;
    }

